# Hyper-V Export failed for virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, export, administration, windows-server-2016

On some machines, when exporting, I am getting the following error:

> Export failed for virtual machine ‘machine’ (xxx-xxx-xxx) with error ‘The requested operation could not be completed due to a virtual disk system limitation. On NTFS, virtual hard disk files must be uncompressed and unencrypted. On ReFS, virtual hard disk files must not have the integrity bit set.’ (0xC03A001A).

Host is both Windows Server 2016 as well as 2012R2, and the filesystem is never compressed, also it is not ReFS, so it is uncompressed, unencrypted NTFS.

I don't know if compression is somehow enabled for the virtual disks, I was not aware of enabling that.

The export target is a network path, the underlying folder is compressed, but that should not matter?!

Some other VMs on the same hosts export fine to the same location.

How can I export the VMs?

Comment: Is the folder which contains the virtual hard disk compressed? If it is compresses, you can see two converging blue arrow on the icon of that folder or on the icon of VHD file.

Comment: No, not compressed. Also not encrypted. It is an SSD, do not know if that makes a difference. It is NTFS.

Comment: VSS (Volume Shadow Copy Service) has a bunch of requirements when the destination is a network target/share. (1) The share server must have SMB v2.1 or better with the *optional* Resiliency Support hot fix. The client and server must be at least Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2 with the hot fix applied. (2) the file system under the share must be NTFS, with compression turned off, encryption turned off and sparse files turned off. (3) for best results the client and server should be in the same active directory and the user should have Full Control on both the Share and File System.